# Have any Orthodox clergy expressed a belief in an impending doomsday/judgment?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, prophecy

For a few months now, I have been receiving unsolicited letters, pamphlets, and bulletins regarding the 'end times', 'coming prophetic storm', 'God's impending judgement', etc.

I have family members who are extremely concerned about Jonathan Cahn's bloodmoon judgement literature (he says the four recent lunar eclipses are a sign from God telling us something crazy is about to happen, I can't distinguish this from astrology).

It seems that a significant percentage of the Protestant church in America believes God will produce some type of upheaval, whether it's the Second Coming or a smaller-scale judgement event, very shortly. Have any Orthodox priests or deacons expressed this belief?

Comment: Actually a very small but very noisy percentage of the American Protestant church, believes this

Comment: How would you define a "notable Orthodox Christian"?

Comment: @Flimzy I would prefer the source for the answer not to be your brother's facebook post (unless he's an authority figure or something).

Comment: True Orthodox Christians know from the bible that we will not know the time God chooses for such things.  I suggest that anyone who thinks they know is going against a direct declaration of Jesus and thus cannot be Orthodox.  One day someone will say "the end is coming" and they'll be right, but that will simply be luck.  For 2000 years certain Christians have thought the end was coming during their lives.  There is nothing new or notable about it.

Comment: @sirdank: That's a pretty weak litmus test. -1

Comment: @DJClayworth do you have any statistics on that statement. What do you consider small?  57 million people seems to be a lot

Comment: @Marc Where did you get 57 million people from?

Comment: @Flimzy Only authority figures is a weak litmus test?

Comment: This almost seems to be asking whether any Orthodox authority figures are dispensational premillennialists.

Comment: @BearinaStudebaker Perhaps I haven't made this clear enough but not all the people espousing this stuff believe it indicates the end times. They simply think that God is delivering some type of judgement and letting the faithful know by astrological signs. It may or may not have anything to do with dispensationalism.

Comment: @sirdank Thanks, that wasn't clear to me. So you're asking if any Orthodox leaders are predicting an impending judgment of (at least) the western world based on the blood moons or similar signs? Do I have your question right?

Comment: Perhaps what you mean by Apocalypse would be helpful.  If you mean Revelation or disclosure of things to come as the bible uses it, then, there should be no worry, unless of course you are not living up to your baptismal commitment.  It is my understanding that th Orthodox, like most other Catholics, Look forward to the 1 time event of Christs Return and the final judgement.  It's in our mutual Creeds,  "We look forward to the 2nd coming of Christ and the Reserection of the Dead"

Comment: @BearinaStudebaker That's it!

Comment: I'm thinking this question might still be too localized (too confined to events happening right now or very very soon) or too broad (too many possible answers) for SE. I understand that that may be frustrating, but I do believe some questions are inherently better for discussion forums than for this site, and this question may be one of them. A forum specifically for EO Christians may be the right place for this question. I'm going to ask [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room) what other people think of that.

Comment: Yes, "authority figure" is a terrible litmus test. How would you define "authority figure?" On whose authority? Considered an authority by whom? By what credentials? Etc.

Comment: @Flimzy The Orthodox church has a clearly-defined ecclesiastical hierarchy in which certain figures are recognized by the entire church as having authority.

Comment: @sirdank: If your question is if any ordaned/official Orthodox clergy have this view, you should ask that. But you asked about "notable" Orthodox, which is quite something else indeed, as an Orthodox could go on a shooting rampage (or do anything else "of note"), to make themselves "notable."

Comment: Your question suffers from a secondary weakness, and that is the definition of "concern." If some ordained Orthodox priest mentioned the impending apocalypse in a prayer, article, blog post, or worship service, would that constitute "concern"? Or would he have to incite his parishioners to do something about it? If so, what?

Comment: In essence, this question is asking for multiple levels of opinionated interpretation... I don't see it as well-scoped question at all. Perhaps it can be edited to be in scope, but I'm not immediately sure how. Perhaps asking if the Orthodox church has made any *official* statements about this would answer your question, and avoid subjectivity?

Comment: @Flimzy Does my edit address your concerns? Admittedly, I still have my own concerns about the question, but I feel it's improved now.

Comment: @BearinaStudebaker: Mmm... I'm not sure if it's any better. I think the OP should be the one to make such substantial edits. Although now it's not ambiguous who the question is asking about, now it's asking about "smaller-scale judgement" which could be almost anything.

Comment: @Flimzy Well, that particular point came from this comment section. See the above exchange between me and sirdank. (And "some type of upheaval" was already in the body of the question anyway.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What @Adam Heeg said.

Matthew 24 is Jesus' description of things to pass before the end times (Ex: [verse 7] "For nation shall rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom: and there shall be famines, and pestilences, and earthquakes, in divers places.").

But these are things that have been happening for a very long time.

And that same chapter (verses 35 - 37) states we won't know until it actually happens: "[35] Heaven and earth shall pass away, but my words shall not pass away. [36] But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of heaven, but my Father only. [37] But as the days of Noe were, so shall also the coming of the Son of man be."

The point is to be presently alert and keep your soul prepared by doing things in the now that God commanded us to do.

BTW, Orthodox Priests do not read from Revelation as part of the yearly Liturgical readings.  Nor do they discuss their own interpretations of it or "end times" in their homilies (sermons).  Though Revelation may be quoted, or groups may have a bible study on it.

Comment: `BTW, Orthodox Priests never read` > Your not, our yes. So dont say for all the priests =)

Comment: Really? A whole book of the Bible is never used in the Orthodox church?

Comment: @DJClayworth - it's not that it's never used in the Church...people have bible studies on it or whatever.  It's just not in the Liturgical readings or sermons.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ - if that is true, then my apologies. I was told that the Liturgical readings never include Genesis or Revelation, and that's also been my experience. Though I have heard Revelation quoted during a Homily before just regarding a description of Heaven.

Comment: Revelation really isn't being included into yearly readings in services, but in preach is included...

Comment: Edited the last point to clarify based on these comments. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question asked.  You essentially argue that Orthodox priests shouldn't endorse end times speculation, but that does not imply that none have.